# SDL Game freezes upon loading second level

Tags: c++, sdl, freeze

The first level of my game builds and plays correctly, as does my second level when I alter the source file to make it load first instead. However, when I complete the first level and load the second, the game freezes. To be specific, all of the images (characters, background etc) render fine, but they are unable to move, and there is no response from the controls (however, debugging does show that keypresses are still being registered).

The file I think is most likely responsible for the problem is my GameScreenManager.ccp.

```
#include "GameScreenManager.h"
#include "GameScreenLevel1.h"
#include "GameScreenLevel2.h"
#include "GameScreen.h"

GameScreenManager::GameScreenManager(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SCREENS startScreen)
{
    mRenderer = renderer;
    mCurrentScreen = NULL;

    //Ensure first screen is set up.
    ChangeScreen(startScreen);
}

GameScreenManager::~GameScreenManager()
{
    mRenderer = NULL;
    delete mCurrentScreen;
    mCurrentScreen = NULL;
}

void GameScreenManager::Update(float deltaTime, SDL_Event e)
{
    if(mCurrentScreen != NULL)
    {
        mCurrentScreen->Update(deltaTime, e);
    }

    //Check if Level 1 is completed
    CompleteCheck();
}

void GameScreenManager::Render()
{
    if(mCurrentScreen != NULL)
    {
        mCurrentScreen->Render();
    }
}

void GameScreenManager::ChangeScreen(SCREENS startScreen)
{
    //Clear up the old screen.
    if(mCurrentScreen != NULL)
    {
        delete mCurrentScreen;
    }
    GameScreenLevel1* tempScreen;
    GameScreenLevel2* tempScreen2;
    switch(startScreen)
    {
        case SCREEN_LEVEL1:
            tempScreen = new GameScreenLevel1(mRenderer);
            mCurrentScreen = (GameScreen*)tempScreen;
            tempScreen = NULL;
        break;
        case SCREEN_LEVEL2:
            tempScreen2 = new GameScreenLevel2(mRenderer);
            mCurrentScreen = (GameScreen*)tempScreen2;
            tempScreen2 = NULL;
        break;
    }
}

void GameScreenManager::CompleteCheck()
{
    if(GameScreenLevel1::complete)
    {
        ChangeScreen(SCREEN_LEVEL2);
    }
}
```

Does anyone think they can spot the issue?

Comment: where do you change the GameScreenLevel1::complete? do you set it to false once you change from level?

Comment: That bool changes in a void in the update function of GameScreenLevel1. Level 2 doesn't have a 'complete', so that can't be the problem.

Comment: well it can, if it always remains true. you will keep changing to level 2 all the time in update. but if you are setting it to false somewhere again after loading second level. then it can't be a problem

Comment: You were right, sorry! Thank you sir :D

Comment: you are welcome, can you mark my answer as correct one. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(GameScreenLevel1::complete)
    {
        ChangeScreen(SCREEN_LEVEL2);
    }
```

seems to always remain true. you need to set it to false after loading the second level.

Comment: A bit delayed, but marked as correct, sorry about that :)